# MS Word, VBA, Set scale to all OLE objects

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, ole

There is MS Word (2013) document with many formulas (more then 1000), created with MathType. They are included into document as OLE objects. Is any simple way to set same value of parameter "scale X", "scale Y" to all of this objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim i  As Integer
    Dim total  As Integer

    total = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
    i = 0
    For Each oIshp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        i = i + 1
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i & " of " & total
        With oIshp
            .ScaleHeight = 100
            .ScaleWidth = 100
        End With
    Next oIshp
```